# Calling jquery.remove() on dom in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

I create paragraph-elements using code like:

```
  var element =  document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode(message);

  element.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("storyConsole").appendChild(element);
```

Then I add the element to an array. I don´t know how to call `jQuery.remove()` on any of those elements in the array. Do you know whether this is possible or not?
Just calling

```
array[0].remove();
```

doesn´t work...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `remove()` as you've stated, is a jQuery method.  If the element is a raw dom element, you will have to wrap it in `$()` first in order to use `remove()`

Comment: This is making the assumption that you are trying to remove the element from the DOM, not the array.

Comment: Thank  you! It worked :)

Comment: Your array doesn't hold a jQuery object. You need to create that before adding it to the array or wrapp a selector around it before calling `remove()`. - Also, `doesn't work` means nothing, you should include `.remove is not a function` so we know what's happening.